# Every aws command fails with different errors without --profile flag

Tags: amazon-web-services

Disclaimer: I do have variable `AWS_PROFILE` set to `default` and echo $AWS_PROFILE does return `default`.

However though, my simple aws commands are failing if I do not pass --profile flag with it.

For example,

if I do `aws2 s3 ls`, then it fails with error : `An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.`

when I do, `aws2 ec2 describe-instances`, it fails with error `An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials`

even though message is different, the underlying problem is same. If I do `aws2 s3 ls --profile default` then it works fine, same with `aws2 ec2 describe-instances` command.

I have no idea how to not need the --profile flag even though I do have `AWS_PROFILE` set.

my credentials file look like following:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIA****
aws_secret_access_key = VpR***
```

My config file looks like following:

```
[default]
region = us-west-1
output = json
```

I have set following two enviroment variables:

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. Also, Ihave echoed their values back and made sure that the values are same exact as in credentials file.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `unset AWS_PROFILE` to remove profile plag.
- Run `aws configure` to update the credential
- Make sure your machine time is correct.

Comment: So `unset AWS_PROFILE` just worked. Which makes me ahppy and curious at the same time because, isn't the netire point behind setting AWS_PROFILE is to make sure each of aws commands run as a default profile?

Comment: As document from amazon. You dont need to set AWS_PROFILE if you want to use default profile

Answer (score 0):

The profile referenced by AWS_PROFILE is invalid or expired. Your default profile is valid. That is why you see the error behavior. Check all credentials via `cat ~/.aws/configure` and remove or correct any that are invalid.

Comment: My config and credentials file both point to default profile. I updated answer with those details as well. One thing though is that I had another profile called `global` in addition to default previously but I deleted all data related to that profile in these files so that there is no confusion

Comment: Ok. What is the AWS_PROFILE environment variable set to?